# Creating WP template from HTML

Tags: templates, wordpress

Hoping some of you WP gurus can point me in the right direction of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm new to WP but experienced in web design.

A client of mine wants to be able to edit/administer his site (and down the line add a blog) but the site is a non-bloggy bespoke design and I'm trying to get my head round adding/converting the various elements into WP for him. I've created a basic WP template with header, footer etc no problem but it's the main content area I could use some pointers on. The main content area HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="main">
  <nav id="showreelnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article id="showreels">
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb1.png" alt="">Title1</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb2.png" alt="">Title2</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb3.png" alt="">Title3</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb4.png" alt="">Title4</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb5.png" alt="">Title5</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb6.png" alt="">Title6</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb7.png" alt="">Title7</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb8.png" alt="">Title8</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb9.png" alt="">Title9</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb10.png" alt="">Title10</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb11.png" alt="">Title11</div>
    <div class="reel"><img src="thumb12.png" alt="">Title12</div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Pretty basic stuff - a category nav and a grid. The nav will remain static across all categories, but how to be able to add/edit a .reel? Not all pages will have 12 thumbs on, some may have less but 12 is max.

Is the Loop the answer here or can I create a template where each object in the grid can be edited or removed? Or create a `div.reel` library item that can be inserted?

Comment: You can try some scripting to loop the html output

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that might help.

Set up a custom page template using a "category" feed loop, then you can just create individual "reel" posts that will get funneled to the page.

The custom loop could look something like this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=5&order=ASC');
```

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

```
    <?php the_content(); ?> 

<?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Here cat=5 is the id number of the category you are routing to the page. Once you selected this as a page template you are using for a particular page, you can just write posts filed under that category and they will output on this page.

If you have multiple pages to do this on, you could create several custom page templates with different categories they are collecting, or maybe use a custom field to choose the category id of the posts you want routed there.

"Starkers" is a good blank theme to start with and customize from there.

I am happy to explain further if you need.

Comment: Thanks Ian, making a bit more sense now. I create a page template based on the HTML above, nav can be static, and the .reel elements would be individual posts?

Answer (score 0):

in WP some content like menu should be generated dynamically by the system and then being styled. for static parts Loop generate nothing, using related plugins can be useful.